# pyspark : how to count by group when the data is highly skewed?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using `pyspark` and I was able to load my `parquet` files using

`df = sqlContext.read.parquet('/mypath/parquet_01')`

the data contains various variables (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, etc), and I would like to

- group by variable `col1`
- count how many obs. there are per group
- return the highest 10 groups in terms of counts (and their respective counts)

I do not want to use `groupby` because the data is very skewed (some `col1` groups have a lot of obs). It seems `reduceByKey` is appropriate here but I am not able to use it correctly..

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post sample data? what does your `df` look like?

Comment: When you say variable `a1`, is that a column name or are `a1, a2, b1` values in a particular column?

Comment: thanks @RakeshAdhikesavan. these are column names. let me modify the example to make that clear

Comment: Can you please update with some test data @Nooble?

Comment: Dataset groupBy is not the same as RDDs - it's RDD reduceByKey with additional features

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 df.select('col1').map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
```

The map procedure is used to create (key, value) pairs: 
The lambda function below is applied to each row of `col1`,

The transformation looks like this:

```
 col1   ->  (col1, 1)
  a         (a,1)
  a         (a,1)
  b         (b,1)
  a         (a,1)
  b         (b,1)
```

Now, we call `reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)` on the key value pairs:
where `a, b` are values of two (key, value) pairs with the same key, which get's reduced to (key, a+b).

So, (a,1) , (a,1) get's reduced to (a,2) and the process continues until only one 'a' key remains, thus giving us the count of the key 'a'

We will be left with this:

```
  col1   ->  (col1, 1)  -> reducedByKey(key,value) 
      a         (a,1)      (a,3)
      a         (a,1)      (b,2)
      b         (b,1)
      a         (a,1)
      b         (b,1)
```

I think groupBy should be faster, even if the data is skewed, reduceByKey is probably slower.

I would also try:

```
 df.groupBy("col1").count()
```

Comment: thanks Rakesh. Can you please explain the `map` procedure? why do we have to create these fake ones? Also, I dont see the key appearing in the reducebykey with the lambda function?!

Comment: Rakesh, out of curiosity, is it possible to create a multiple key?